# how to validation interval value in vue/element-ui

Tags: validation, vue.js, element-ui

I have a form, which contains an interval value. How do I verify the min value and max value of the interval?

Form:

```
  <el-form ref="form" :model="form" :rules="rules" label-width="144px">
    <el-form-item label="Interval Value">
      <el-col :span="5">
        <el-input-number :controls="false" v-model="form.min"/>
      </el-col>
      <el-col :span="1">-</el-col>
      <el-col :span="5">
        <el-input-number :controls="false" v-model="form.max"/>
      </el-col>
    </el-form-item>
  </el-form>
```

Rules:

```
  rules: {
    min: [
      {required: true, message: 'enter min value', trigger: 'blur'}
    ],
    max: [
      {required: true, message: 'enter max value', trigger: 'blur'}
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Do you just want the require validations? you have to specify the prop attribute on the `el-form-item` =>  `prop="min"` and `prop="max"`

Comment: In fact, it is because I use the `=` to set the default value. When I use `$set`, it is ok. Thank you.